# How to store results into a Map in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I need one help.
I have a table - ACCOUNT which stores USER_ID and ACCOUNT_DETAIL. There are multiple records for a single USER_ID with different ACCOUNT_DETAIL.
I want to store this records in a Map where USER_ID will be the key and List of Account will be the value.  I get the list of USER_ID 
from USER table. Then for each of those user id I need to get account details.

I can populate that map by implementing below algorithm\logic :

**Step 1 :** Fetch userIds from USER table and store it in a list - userList

**Step 2:**

```
for (User user : userList) {

// Make a DB call to ACCOUNT table for user.id
// Put those details in the map - map.put(user.id, accountList)
}
```

But here the issue is, if USER table is having 1K records I have to make 1K db calls from that loop which will end up with a performance issue.
Could you please tell me if there is any better approach through which I can achieve this using hibernate ?

Comment: it means that u already understood that map wont support pagination ? thus not really a good option for such data structures. Whats is the overall use-case ? some background batch processing ? or this has to run for each user ?

Comment: @AntJavaDev as per the use case this has to run for each user. Its not a batch job

Comment: hmmm, then u have to perform a custom pagination to cover the total User / Account mapping. Another question just to understand why you need a map, in your example, for just one user, you are going to fetch all others user's data as well? or there is another linkage? or the map always would contain one USER_ID?

Answer (score -1):

Use the HQL join query(ACCOUNT and USER) to get all the accounts and construct the map by iterating the accounts.

```
select acc from Account acc, User usr where acc.userId = usr.id
```